# Retrofit + RxJava fails to cache responses - Android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-android, okhttp

I am using from bellow libraries in my project for connect to service and then I get a list of value from service and I fill with them the my spinner :

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

**Problem :** How can I caching my list of adapter for 48 hours or I update my spinner list every 48 hour from service.

Bellow is my `RetrofitApi class` ,but call service when I open app and I can't cache for 48 hour:

```
public class RetrofitApi {
    private static PublicApi retrofit = null;

    public static PublicApi getClient(String url) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();

                    request = new Request.Builder()
                            .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder()
                                    .maxAge(2, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                                    .minFresh(48, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                                    .maxStale(48, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                                    .build())
                            .url(request.url())
                            .build();


                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            }).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(PublicApi.class);

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Then I connect to my service like bellow :

```
PublicApi publicApi = retrofitApi.getClient("https://xxx.xxx.xxx", context);
mCompositeDisposable.add(publicApi.language("getLanguages")
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(language -> responseLanguage(language, resultListener), language -> errorLanguage(language, resultListener)));
```

Comment: You mean to update the list in the app only for when the user open it? Or do you need to show any notifications after a 48h cycle?

Comment: You mean to update the list in the app only for when the user open it? yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import com.bumptech.glide.util.Util;
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import xxx.xxx.xxx.tools.Utils;
import okhttp3.Cache;
import okhttp3.CacheControl;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

/**
 * Created by admin on 7/11/2017.
 */

public class RetrofitApi {
    private static PublicApi retrofit = null;
    private Context context;


    public PublicApi getClient(String url, Context context, Integer value) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
        this.context = context;
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            if (value == 1) {
                //For get Log see D/OkHttp
                HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                // set your desired log level
                logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
                File httpCacheDirectory = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "responses");
                int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
                Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    okHttpClient = builder.
                            addNetworkInterceptor(REWRITE_RESPONSE_INTERCEPTOR)
                            .addInterceptor(OFFLINE_INTERCEPTOR)
                            .addInterceptor(logging)
                            .cache(cache)
                            .build();
                } else {
                    okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                            .addNetworkInterceptor(REWRITE_RESPONSE_INTERCEPTOR)
                            .addInterceptor(OFFLINE_INTERCEPTOR)
                            .addInterceptor(logging)
                            .cache(cache)
                            .build();
                }


            } else {
                okHttpClient = builder.build();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                //.client(httpClient.build())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(PublicApi.class);

        return retrofit;
    }

    private Interceptor REWRITE_RESPONSE_INTERCEPTOR = chain -> {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        String cacheControl = originalResponse.header("Cache-Control");

        if (cacheControl == null || cacheControl.contains("no-store") || cacheControl.contains("no-cache") ||
                cacheControl.contains("must-revalidate") || cacheControl.contains("max-age=0")) {
            return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                    .removeHeader("Pragma")
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 60)
                    .build();
        } else {
            return originalResponse;
        }
    };


    private Interceptor OFFLINE_INTERCEPTOR = chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request();
        //if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 2; // tolerate 2-days stale
        request = request.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                .build();
        // }

        return chain.proceed(request);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to achieve is refreshing your data than you should avoid timers, there are some major drawbacks for fixed interval timer like battery drain, Other solutions such as push notification might be more useful, More info about the drawbacks here:

[Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#tradeoffs)

If you still want to use a timer than this might help:

```
scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    //Schedule a task to run at fixed rate    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do stuff here!

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Do stuff to update UI here!
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "timer ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 48, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```